# Appengine Datastore Record Cannot be deleted or changed

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

This one is probably an appengine fluke and a bug, but I'd love to hear if anyone has any suggestions.

I discovered that a single datastore record is behaving strangely by showing up at the beginning of a query on a datetime field sorted by oldest to newest, although the date was newer than all of the other records. On closer inspection I discovered that the datetime field in the record always shows the current date.  I tried to programatically change the date and it would always reset to the current datetime. I then tried to delete or change the value on the record in the datastore viewer and there was no effect.

No matter what I try the record cannot be changed or deleted. This record is blocking all query functionality on an important table and it is impossible to affect it.

Comment: This error appears to be a bug caused by the May 25th App Engine outage.  I just received an email discussing "unapplied writes" from app engine and brought up the issue with them.  They seem to think that it is related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was caused by a bug from the May 25th App Engine outage. After emailing the app engine team they have resolved the issue on the back-end.